# Excel-VBA: changing chart series color for a dynamic table based on specific parameters

Tags: excel, excel-2010, dashboard, vba

I have the following issue in Excel:

I have a dynamic table that will feed a graph (stacked area), the results of the lookup function return a table that will hide the values which are "empty"

The issue here is that for different chosen parameters (country), I get a different number of data series (market players) and in a different order.

I have a helper column in that table which returns a value in the same line as the company that I want in a different color.

[image]
I have some space in the table due to the possibility of having more MPs, then the table is filtered and the graph is generated.

The issue is that I am trying to first: **count the series, so I will not have an error for trying to reference missing series on the VBA (e.g. when I have code for 5 series but the lookup only returns three)**. and second: **Identify the row with the company name on it (DT) and make it an specific color in the chart and the others will be different shades of gray**

What I am trying to do is (only parts of it because there is no space for everything):

```
    'Only display non-zero values in the chart chart
    Sheets("Financials").ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=7
    Sheets("Financials").ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:= _
            "IN"

    Dim iSrs As Long, nSrs As Long

    If Sheets("Financials").Range("f98") = "" Then
        GoTo EndPie:
    End If

    With Worksheets("NatCo Dashboard").ChartObjects("Chart 9")
        nSrs = Worksheets("NatCo Dashboard").ChartObjects("Chart 9").Chart.SeriesCollection.Count
        For iSrs = 1 To nSrs
            Select Case nSrs
                Case 1
                    Select Case Sheets("Financials").Range("m98")
                        Case "DT"
                            Worksheets("NatCo Dashboard").ChartObjects("Chart 9").Chart.SeriesCollection(iSrs).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(226, 0, 116)
                        Case "Orange"
                            Worksheets("NatCo Dashboard").ChartObjects("Chart 9").Chart.SeriesCollection(iSrs).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 153, 0)
                        Case "EE"
                            Worksheets("NatCo Dashboard").ChartObjects("Chart 9").Chart.SeriesCollection(iSrs).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(52, 161, 160)
                        Case Else
                            Worksheets("NatCo Dashboard").ChartObjects("Chart 9").Chart.SeriesCollection(iSrs).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(217, 217, 217)
                    End Select
                Case 2
                    Select Case Sheets("Financials").Range("m98")
                        Case "DT"
                            Worksheets("NatCo Dashboard").ChartObjects("Chart 9").Chart.SeriesCollection(iSrs).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(226, 0, 116)
                            Worksheets("NatCo Dashboard").ChartObjects("Chart 9").Chart.SeriesCollection(iSrs).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(217, 217, 217)
                        Case "Orange"
                            Worksheets("NatCo Dashboard").ChartObjects("Chart 9").Chart.SeriesCollection(iSrs).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 153, 0)
                            Worksheets("NatCo Dashboard").ChartObjects("Chart 9").Chart.SeriesCollection(iSrs).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(217, 217, 217)
                        Case "EE"
                            Worksheets("NatCo Dashboard").ChartObjects("Chart 9").Chart.SeriesCollection(iSrs).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(52, 161, 160)
                            Worksheets("NatCo Dashboard").ChartObjects("Chart 9").Chart.SeriesCollection(iSrs).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(217, 217, 217)
                        Case Else
                            Worksheets("NatCo Dashboard").ChartObjects("Chart 9").Chart.SeriesCollection(iSrs).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(217, 217, 217)
                            Worksheets("NatCo Dashboard").ChartObjects("Chart 9").Chart.SeriesCollection(iSrs).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(190, 190, 190)
End Select
                Select Case Sheets("Financials").Range("m99")
                    Case "DT"
                        Worksheets("NatCo Dashboard").ChartObjects("Chart 9").Chart.SeriesCollection(iSrs).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(217, 217, 217)
                        Worksheets("NatCo Dashboard").ChartObjects("Chart 9").Chart.SeriesCollection(iSrs).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(226, 0, 116)
                    Case "Orange"
                        Worksheets("NatCo Dashboard").ChartObjects("Chart 9").Chart.SeriesCollection(iSrs).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(217, 217, 217)
                        Worksheets("NatCo Dashboard").ChartObjects("Chart 9").Chart.SeriesCollection(iSrs).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 153, 0)
                    Case "EE"
                        Worksheets("NatCo Dashboard").ChartObjects("Chart 9").Chart.SeriesCollection(iSrs).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(217, 217, 217)
                        Worksheets("NatCo Dashboard").ChartObjects("Chart 9").Chart.SeriesCollection(iSrs).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(52, 161, 160)
                    Case Else
                        Worksheets("NatCo Dashboard").ChartObjects("Chart 9").Chart.SeriesCollection(iSrs).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(217, 217, 217)
                        Worksheets("NatCo Dashboard").ChartObjects("Chart 9").Chart.SeriesCollection(iSrs).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(190, 190, 190)
                End Select
            Case 3
```

Then it goes like this until Case 5 (max number possible)

The problem is that eventually, the chart turns everything into grey, 
[image]

Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong or even a better or more appropriate (cleaner) way for doing this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Use a PivotTable and a PivotChart?  With a Page Filter for "IN", this should do exactly what you want.

Comment: @Chronocidal, thank you for the advice! Actually, the filter is the filter is not a problem I guess, the issue I have is to address the correct colors to the correct series

Comment: Is there a problem with Else clauses `Worksheets("NatCo Dashboard").ChartObjects("Chart 9").Chart.SeriesCollection(iSrs).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(217, 217, 217)`? This is setting them to grey?

Comment: @SJR, that is correct, I have changed the indexes and its partially working, trying to figure out the rest

Comment: Can you post a shot of the chart before the code?